# Two versions of ArcGIS Engine SDK on same computer?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-engine, sdk, arcobjects

I wish to be able to develop against both ArcGIS Engine 9.3 **and** 10.2, so that for example, an application could depend on either at runtime.

Are there any issues with having the SDKs for both on a developer PC?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying. Given that 9.3 is "retired" and that the licensing constants changed at 10.0 and again at 10.1, I doubt it would be possible.  If you need to develop on multiple platforms, using one code base (with branches for different releases) and multiple release builds (with VMs for each build environment) is the way to roll.

Comment: I was under the impression that versions of ArcGis are mutually exclusive - only one can be installed at a time, as they use the same registry settings and put the binaries in the windows GAC only the most recent install will be found. If you must have two versions (as I do) then you will need to run virtual PC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC which is 'free' with Windows 7. Be aware that 9.3 can consume a v10 license but with a virtual PC that's 1 license for the workstation and 1 for each virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/40182) in the ESRI forum quotes a (now removed(!!)) 'Common Question' from the [ArcGIS Common Questions page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/new/common-questions):

Can ArcGIS 10 be installed on the same machine as ArcGIS 9.3.1?

> No. For users who want to install ArcGIS 10 and ArcGIS 9.3.1 on the
>   same machine, Esri recommends using a virtualization tool (such as VM
>   Ware's VM Workstation or Microsoft's Virtual PC) and install the new
>   instance of ArcGIS on that virtual machine.
>
> We had initially announced that we would be able to support running
>   ArcGIS 10 and ArcGIS 9.3.1 on the same machine. However, we were not
>   able to accomplish this for ArcGIS 10.

The following drawbacks to trying to do this have been suggested to me:

- The registration of the COM components would be messed up
- Mutually exclusive registry settings

So to develop a .NET library that could depend on either version of ArcGIS is going to require (at least):

- Two separate versions of the affected library
- Two solution files
- Assemblies dependent on the library will load the library at runtime rather than have a reference to the library